# Accessing Choices Value of PositiveSmallIntegerField in Django Template

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this:

```
class SomeModeL(Model):
    MODEL_TYPE = (
        (0, 'Type1'), 
        (1, 'Type2'), 
        (2, 'Type3')
        )
    model_type = PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=MODEL_TYPE)
```

Now, I passed in an instance of the model into context and want to access the model_type, specifically the String, such as 'Type1'

So, in the template, i do this: {{ some_model.model_type }} but this returns the integer, not the string. How do I get the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [**`get_fieldname_display`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) (where you replace *`fieldname`* with the name of the field you want "translate" in its textual representation) to get the corresponding value, so:

```
{{ some_model.get_model_type_display }}
```

Comment: hi, how can I use this in .filter().values("fieldname")